# Difference of dates using lag function postgres

Tags: postgresql, datediff

I have customer ID and transaction Date(yyyy-mm-dd) as shown below

```
Cust_id Trans_date
1       2017-01-01
1       2017-01-03
1       2017-01-06
2       2017-01-01
2       2017-01-04
2       2017-01-05
```

I need to find the difference in no_of_days for each transaction grouped at Cust_id

I tried with date_diff and extract using lag function, but I am getting error

> function lag(timestamp without time zone) may only be called as a window function

I looking for the result as below

```
Cust_id Trans_date difference
1       2017-01-01   0
1       2017-01-03   3
1       2017-01-05   2 
2       2017-01-01   0
2       2017-01-04   4
2       2017-01-05   1
```

How to find the difference in postgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you want?

```
with t(Cust_id,Trans_date) as( 
    select 1       ,'2017-01-01'::timestamp union all
    select 1       ,'2017-01-03'::timestamp union all
    select 1       ,'2017-01-06'::timestamp union all
    select 2       ,'2017-01-01'::timestamp union all
    select 2       ,'2017-01-04'::timestamp union all
    select 2       ,'2017-01-05'::timestamp 
)

select 
Cust_id, 
Trans_date, 
coalesce(Trans_date::date - lag(Trans_date::date) over(partition by Cust_id order by Trans_date), 0) as difference
from t;
```